# Can stars gravitationally shield a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, accretion-disk

Is it possible to arrange a set of massive objects such as stars in orbit around a black hole such that objects of lesser mass cannot physically reach and fall into the event horizon of the black hole?

This could be similar to how [Jupiter may protect the Earth from long period comets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18492/47727).

In other words, could there be several star systems with the black hole in their center, such that any possible object on approach to the black hole would be gravitationally deflected away from the black hole?

Comment: Does arranging in orbits with sufficient angular momentum count?

Comment: I get the impression you're taking the expression "hole" far too literally.

Comment: Hey what ever means.. the goal is to gravitationally move an object away from event horizon..by an arrangement of stars or planets’ orbits.. I know Blackhole ‘lacks hole’ . Upto,  say a given maximum mass. Obviously, another approaching BH.. is a bummer

Comment: You could try a [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere), but there are a lot of problems with the idea.

Comment: I did a major edit since I think the title and wording obscured a not bad question.  I am pretty sure the short answer is no, but longer answers might be interesting.

Comment: I wrote an answer saying "yes", so I wonder what I got wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is yes: From a distance, the gravitation of a black hole cannot be distinguished from that a normal star of the same mass. So you can have a very large planet orbiting the black hole - it just needs to have enough angular momentum (speed) to maintain this orbit. Now you can imagine instead of one planet, you can have a thousand or a million of these planets all orbiting the black hole. Presumably, if any asteroid or something tries to enter this system from a distance it will have a high chance of being caught by the gravitational pull of one of these planets and enter orbit of that planet (or crash into it) instead of going into the black hole in the center.

Comment: I think the answer is yes too, although any object of lesser mass "rescued" from its trajectory with the event horizon by orbiting objects would be held in its new orbit by the black hole's gravity as well as that of the rescuer(s). Long term answer is no.

Comment: Thanks ! Appreciate the response. Assume it is a supermassive Blackhole. Can Stars be in use for such a purpose?  Won't that explain a cluster of Stars orbiting near Galaxy cores? Over time, say a bunch of such planets gets into the Orbit of rescuer 'Stars'...Then Voila!  We have something akin to a Solar system formation...right? Can we experimentally(Observationally) verify that this may be the case for certain Galaxies i.e. no object up to a mass 'm' can possibly enter its Core? or Not? Thanks again...